# Kivy change image resolution on Android

Tags: android, python, kivy

I use plyer on a Kivy app for Android to take photos from camera. It works fine. I get an image about 5 MB every time.

My problem is when I browse images on a filechooser it is very slow, because of the image size I suppose. I thought that I could keep smaller size images every time I save an image from camera.

The code I use is:

```
from plyer import camera
...
camera.take_picture(filename=filepath,
                        on_complete=self.camera_callback)
```

I want to save an extra converted image but I can't find a way to do this in Android.

How can I do this?